# Postmaster email issues

Tags: email, postmaster

Currently we are using Postmaster to send all automated email, we are very happy to see such module.

Unfortunately we got some issues with it;

1. All email that has been sending with the ExpressionEngine service got equal signs in the mail. We already check the NewLine and the CRLF, but all options are failing.
2. Mandrill gives us some error: "Mandrill Service - Error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

PHP version : 5.3.13 and running Wamp.

Answer (score 1):

Please send bug reports to support@objectivehtml.com. I will be able to help you a lot better there.

StackExchange is best left for usage questions, not technical support issues (bugs) as I need to ask a series of questions before I can give an answer. I have not experience any of these issues first hand though, but I am sure there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with cURL's ability to communicate over SSL, and this solution worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495053/1919543